# How to get part of the URL using java

Tags: java

My URL is:

> /app/a/ui/1234/test.jsp

What is the best way to get `1234` alone using java?

Comment: tried using substring

Comment: Do you have the URL in a `String`? Have a look at the API documentation of class [`java.lang.String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). There are methods in there that you can use for this task. For example, the `split` method.

Comment: Show us  what you have tried ...

Comment: Instead of reducing my points u can tell the answer. What is the use to you for reducing points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way is, split your expression with "/"  and get the 3rd index.

Comment: Thank you..  I will try in this way..

Answer (score 2):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");

Matcher m = p.matcher("/app/a/ui/1234/876test.jsp");
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}

Output: 
1234
876
```

From the above code you can easily get your expected result.

Comment: If my url contains more than str="/app/a/ui/1234/ui/122222/test.jsp";

like this means i will face problem. I need to get 4th param value alone

Comment: You should let OP to provide his or her effect on the question he/she has..

Comment: @Sangeetha.V Check my updated answer. That will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Shiladittya. I will check and update. Thank you so much..

Comment: This one working fine. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
String str = " :/app/a/ui/1234/test.jsp ";
int i = str.lastIndexOf('1');
int j = str.lastindexOf('/');
String str2 = str.subString(i,j);
System.out.println(str2);
```

Output is:

> 1234

Comment: Please mind that your code won't compile at the current state.

Comment: String str = " :/app/a/ui/1234/test.jsp ";
int i = str.lastIndexOf('1');
int j = str.lastIndexOf('/');
String str2 = str.substring(i,j);
System.out.println(str2);

Comment: Please add this code into your answer.